# Duplicate storage entry

Tags: contract-design, storage

How can we prevent duplicate data entry in Blockchain? For example, in case of identity storage, how do we make sure that the details of a person (set of name, ssn, dob, etc) being sent to the Smart Contract was never sent earlier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you want something more language-agnostic, but in Solidity it could look something like this:

```
contract Ashish {
  struct Entry {
    uint age;
    uint securityNumber;
    bool isSet;
  }

  mapping(bytes32 => Entry) myData;

  function addData(uint age, uint ssn) {
    bytes32 key = sha3(age, ssn);
    require(!myData[key].isSet);
    myData[key] = Entry(age, ssn, true);
  }
}
```

Basically, you can use a hash of the data you want to store as the key, and store the data in a mapping as the value for that key. If the identical data was set before, the `require` will throw an exception.

You can also use something else as the key, as long as you know it will be unique (for example, the SSN you suggested, or similar).